# Can argon be dangerous for a living species?

Tags: science-based, biology

First, the argon is a chemical element and the third-most abundant gas in the Earth's atmosphere (approximatively 1%). And I know that when someone  inhales a large amount of argon, there is a risk of asphyxiation by anoxia, but that's not what i'm looking for.

So, i would like to know if there is any species that when they get in contact or breathe it they die, or something similar (getting sickness which lead to a dead state).

I would like to know if there is any others chemicals elements/materials who can be destroyed by the Argon.

And if possible, could you tell me what kind of objects are mostly made of Argon ?

Comment: Not chemically dangerous but Argon Fluorine lasers are pretty cool.  Deep UV emissions.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon_fluoride_laser\

Comment: Argon and other noble gases may cause narcosis

Comment: Seems reasonable enough, after all, kryptonite is dangerous for superman! [Scifi.SE question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23022/is-kryptonite-made-of-the-element-krypton)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you look where argon is on the periodic table, it's far on the right, along with the other "noble" gases. The noble gases are gases that, well, they don't really do much. From [Wikipedia, *noble gas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas):

> The noble gases make up a group of chemical elements with similar properties; under standard conditions, they are all odorless, colorless, monatomic gases with very low chemical reactivity. The six noble gases that occur naturally are helium, neon, argon, krypton, xenon, and the radioactive radon.

Nobel gases do glow a bit when you put enough electric potential across them (e.g., neon lights), but they don't really do anything else. So it is highly unlikely that argon will be toxic to anything because (as far as I understand it, not being a biologist) toxins work by interacting with other elements and disrupting the chemistry of the host.

However, the dominant gas in Earth's atmosphere is nitrogen, and while it is pretty stable, it is probably more feasible that an entity is poisoned by the nitrogen in our atmosphere than the argon.

Answer (score 9):

According to Wikipedia's article on nitrogen intoxication, argon is 2.3 times as intoxicating as nitrogen ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_narcosis#Causes)). A 80% Ar / 20 O2 atmosphere, at sea-level, would make humans a little woozy, but not cause any serious harm.

Comment: Be careful what you mean by "80% Ar / 20% O2". Argon in a lot less dense than N2 (molecular weight 18 compared with 24) and one critical parameter is that the *partial pressure* of O2 in the gas mixture you are breathing matches the partial pressure of O2 in air.

Answer (score 3):

Just make the argon either Argon-39 or Argon-42. Both have medium term half lives-232 year or 33 year and are electron emitters. That is neither so long that the emission rate is trivial or so short that it isn't around for very long. Electron emitters can penetrate a few millimetres and tend to produce gamma radiation with some barriers. 1% of either in air would really bad for living things such as severe mutation and probably severe cancer leading to death.